# dynamically detect change to span element

Tags: jquery

I have span elements that are dynamically generated from an ajax response. I am trying to detect a change to the span value using the below code and it seems to work in jsfiddle with fixed elements but not in a real scenario where data is dynamically generated. The span values are updated with setInterval function number increment which i am trying to detect.

The steps i am taking are - would appreciate some advice on why my code would not be working?

1. For all elements with an id containing "minutes" <- these will be my span elements
2. Get the id's
3. Detect any change in all elements with id's from step 2
4. When change detected, get the span element value
5. Check if span value is greater than 00 i.e. 01 (this is actually a minute value)
6. If condition from step 5 is met then apply css
7. If condition from step 5 is not met then remove css

```
$('[id*="minutes"]').each(function() {
    spanid = $(this).attr('id');

    console.log(spanid);

    $("#"+spanid).on('change',function(){

        spanval = $(this).text();
        id = $(this).attr('id').charAt(0);

        if(spanval > 00) {
            $('#results').text(span);

            $("#"+id+"-wt-html").css({"background":"#FFE95B", "color":"red"});
        } else {
            $("#"+id+"-wt-html").removeAttr("style")
       }
    });
});
```

**sample HTML**

```
<td id="9-wt-html">
<div id="9-wt-ajax">
<span id="9-hours">00</span>:
<span id="9-minutes">15</span>:
<span id="9-seconds">12</span>
</div>
</td>
```

The above span elements are created before the ajax call using a fixed script below:

```
for (var key in skills_arr) {
//console.log(skills_arr[key]+" - "+key);
$('#Table > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+skills_arr[key]+'</td><td id="'+key+'-cw-html"><div id="'+key+'-cw-ajax"></div></td><td id="'+key+'-aa-html"><div id="'+key+'-aa-ajax"></div></td><td id="'+key+'-wt-html"><div id="'+key+'-wt-ajax"><span id="'+key+'-hours">00</span>:<span id="'+key+'-minutes">00</span>:<span id="'+key+'-seconds">00</span></div></td><td id="'+key+'-op-html"><div id="'+key+'-op-ajax"></div></td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: Please share your HTML.

Comment: If you add this before you generate the spans it will not work

Comment: i added it at the bottom of my script file after the spans are created but I don't get past step 2

Comment: You said span elements that are dynamically generated from an ajax response so adding at the bottom dont mean that spans are generated before attaching the events

Comment: @user3436467 Please confirm whether your span is generated dynamically by ajax response or they are static and just their values will be changed from ajax response?

Comment: @Aaruna, correct. the spans are created with before ajax. the values are updated with setinterval after ajax call. i will update my post with how the span elements are created

Comment: @user3436467 I have fixed your code below with a working `snippet` based on my understanding. The span value and the row color will change after 3 seconds by `setInterval`. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have created a `snippet` below based on my understandings.

Also, would like to highlight the below points.

> For `span` element, we can't listen for the `change` event. Instead,
>   the code below will listen for the `DOMSubtreeModified` event.
>
> Also, we can directly listen for the event of the element using
>   `$('[id*="minutes"]').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){})` if the
>   element exists before this line.
>
> Otherwise, we have to listen the same from its `parent` or `document`
>   as given below.

```js
$('#Table').on('DOMSubtreeModified', '[id*="minutes"]', function() {
    var span = $(this);
    var spanValue = parseInt(span.text());
    var id = span.attr('id').charAt(0);
    if(spanValue > 0) {
            //$('#results').text(span); // Not sure what is this?

            $("#"+id+"-wt-html").css({"background":"#FFE95B", "color":"red"});
    } else {
            $("#"+id+"-wt-html").removeAttr("style")
    }
});

var skills_arr = {
  '9': 'some value here'
};

for (var key in skills_arr) {
$('#Table > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+skills_arr[key]+'</td><td id="'+key+'-cw-html"><div id="'+key+'-cw-ajax"></div></td><td id="'+key+'-aa-html"><div id="'+key+'-aa-ajax"></div></td><td id="'+key+'-wt-html"><div id="'+key+'-wt-ajax"><span id="'+key+'-hours">00</span>:<span id="'+key+'-minutes">00</span>:<span id="'+key+'-seconds">00</span></div></td><td id="'+key+'-op-html"><div id="'+key+'-op-ajax"></div></td></tr>');
}

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#9-minutes').text('15');
  $('#9-seconds').text('12');
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#9-minutes').text('00');
  $('#9-seconds').text('10');
}, 6000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Table">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>Results:</p>
<div id="#results">
</div>
```

Comment: Thx very much. This seems to be working well in  my lab so far.. running a few more tests and ill come back

Comment: @user3436467 Sure :-)

Comment: `$('#results').text(span);` was from messing around. please remove it from your solution

Comment: @user3436467 Sure, I don't know what it is and mentioned the same in the comment. I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason it might not be working is because you are enclosing divs inside td. You need to enclose them in div to work:

```
<div id="9-wt-html">
  <div id="9-wt-ajax">
    <span id="9-hours">00</span>:
    <span id="9-minutes">15</span>:
    <span id="9-seconds">12</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your jQuery code you need to transform span text to integre to work:

```
$('[id*="minutes"]').each(function() {
  spanid = $(this).attr('id');

  console.log(spanid);

  $("#" + spanid).on('change', function() {

    spanval = parseInt($(this).text());
    id = $(this).attr('id').charAt(0);

    if (spanval > 00) {
      //$('#results').text(span); // ?where is span variable?

      $("#" + id + "-wt-html").css({
        "background": "#FFE95B",
        "color": "red"
      });
    } else {
      $("#" + id + "-wt-html").removeAttr("style")
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f90dqmpm/)

Comment: it needs to be within the td since i am actually applying the css to the td not the div.. unfortunately i couldnt figure out how to make a div full width of bootstrap table cell so i am applying the css to the td instead